# SQL Error: Only a SQL server provider is allowed on this instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-on-linux

While connected to a local sql server database, I can make queries to retrieve and write data. However, this query fails:

```
SELECT 
    *
INTO
    #tmp_table
FROM OPENROWSET
    (  
        'MSDASQL'
        ,'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}'
        ,'select * from csv_filePath'
    );
```

with the error message: SQL Error [7222] [S0255]: Only a SQL Server provider is allowed on this instance.

I am using dbeaver on Linux Mint 19.2. I tried the same command on SQL Server Management Studio on a windows VM, but got the same message. My firewall is set up as in the picture below:
[image: Firewall config]

Please help.

Comment: It looks like your local sql database does not allow the Microsoft Access Driver. Is this a full sql server or a sql express instance?

Comment: You do not give the path of the file you are trying to read. Try putting the filename in the `Select` statement. e.g. `'select * from C:\Test.CSV'`

Comment: SQL Server on Linux does not support linked server types other than other SQL Server instances. That is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2017?view=sql-server-ver15#Unsupported).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, SQL Server on Linux does not support Linked servers for anything other than other SQL Servers. From the documentation [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2017 on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2017?view=sql-server-ver15#Unsupported):

> ### Unsupported features & services
>
> The following features and services are not available SQL Server 2017 on Linux. The support of these features will be increasingly enabled over time.
>
> ```
> Area                Unsupported feature or service
> Database engine     Merge replication
>                     Stretch DB
>                     PolyBase
>                     Distributed query with 3rd-party connections
>                     Linked Servers to data sources other than SQL Server
>                     System extended stored procedures (XP_CMDSHELL, etc.)
>                     Filetable, FILESTREAM
>                     CLR assemblies with the EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE permission set
>                     Buffer Pool Extension
> ```

Notice that it specifically states *"Linked Servers to data sources other than SQL Server"*. If you need a linked server to a different source, you will need to use SQL Server on Windows at this time.

Comment: Ugh... just ran face first into this...  Same on 2019.